# Salesforce Legacy Systems/Features

Tags: general

The term "legacy" is being used quite a lot in IT as I found out. The synonym for this term would be "outdated". Why not use the term "outdated" instead of "legacy" and could you provide an example of legacy systems in Salesforce or its legacy features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not use the term "outdated" instead of "legacy"

Both are probably used, but I expect it's because it's become industry *jargon* (that is, words that have taken on a special meaning in a particular industry) and it has a lot of momentum. The same reason why machinists call some tools "jobbers" and other tools "stubs", and why framers use "square", "plumb", and "true".

To me, "legacy" is used to describe more than simply "outdated". It means

- this thing has been around for a while
- this thing used to be owned by someone else (e.g. code that existed before a newly hired developer started working)
- this thing will be hard to change, because people and systems have gotten used to its behavior (and any change to the output will break things)